# Use volume keys under Linux

Tags: keyboard, audio, crunchbang

I have a keyboard that is just a generic Gateway one that I got with my PC. I was wondering if it was possible to use the volume keys on it. I have the output from `xev` after pressing both the volume up and volume down keys.

```
KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x162, subw 0x0, time 3904956, (-45,-188), root:(378,348),
state 0x0, keycode 122 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x162, subw 0x0, time 3905056, (-45,-188), root:(378,348),
state 0x0, keycode 122 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x162, subw 0x0, time 3906475, (-45,-188), root:(378,348),
state 0x0, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x162, subw 0x0, time 3906574, (-45,-188), root:(378,348),
state 0x0, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So, what can I do to get these to change my volume under [Crunchbang Linux](http://crunchbanglinux.org)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubuntu, an easy (usually) way is to install [KeyTouch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyTouch). If your keyboard is not supported out of the box, you need both the `keytouch` and `keytouch-editor` packages. Run the keytouch editor, and configure your keyboard.

Other relevant Ubuntu wiki pages are [Hotkeys/Troubleshooting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting) (but try KeyTouch first) and [Hotkeys/Architecture](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Architecture) (explaining this is not as simple a it should be under the hood).

I don't know how relevant this information is for Crunchbang, which is based on Ubuntu but might have changed things related to keyboard configuration.

Comment: I tried KeyTouch and the Ubuntu Wiki pages without success. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

In a similar situation on a laptop, I let the window manager (Fluxbox) handle the events via the following keyboard shortcuts in `~/.fluxbox/keys`:

```
XF86AudioLowerVolume    :ExecCommand amixer sset -q Master,0 5%- 
XF86AudioRaiseVolume    :ExecCommand amixer sset -q Master,0 5%+ 
XF86AudioMute           :ExecCommand amixer sset -q Master,0 toggle
```

Crunchbang uses OpenBox as default as I understand, so maybe the solution is similar to my Fluxbox one.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm on my laptop with Arch using Fluxbox, and I was trying to figure out what to insert into ~/.fluxbox/keys! I couldn't figure out the keycodes or the alsa command.. Thank you again, this just made my day. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [configure a hal policy](http://hal.freedesktop.org/quirk/quirk-keymap-index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I chucked in my rc.xml

```
    <keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
  <action name="Execute">
    <execute>amixer sset -q Master,0 5%+</execute>
  </action>
</keybind> 
<keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
  <action name="Execute">
    <execute>amixer sset -q Master,0 5%-</execute>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioMute">
  <action name="Execute">
    <execute>ExecCommand amixer sset -q Master,0 toggle</execute>
  </action>
</keybind>
```